# Unable to load scripts before user authentication

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, authentication

My jQuery file in the `Scripts` folder is showing up as 404 on the login screen even though the path is correct. I've researched a lot of solutions, but nothing seems to be working. I am trying to use jQuery to show a loader when the user clicks a login button.

Button:

```
<asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btnLogin" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-large" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"></asp:Button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function() {
$("#loader").show();
});
```

CSS:

```
#loader {
animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
clip: rect(0, 80px, 80px, 40px); 
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 40px);
top: calc(90% - 40px);
display: none;
}
```

jQuery reference:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

I've made 100% sure the path is correct. I tried this in my Web.Config with no success as well:

```
<location allowOverride="false" path="~/Scripts">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This has been driving me insane for about an hour now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to reference jQuery with a from the user directory using `~` (unix style)? If so then it doesn't work that way. You should include jQuery in your web server and then use a relative or absolute path there.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right. Took away the `~` and it worked. *facepalm*

Comment: I'm used to MVC's `.cshtml` where this will work. Did not realize it didn't when using web form's `.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

as workaround, while you trying to get it solved you can use jQuery from CDN (like //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js). If no chance to get it from internet, you can setup another site on IIS to serve static files and use it as your local CDN :)